# How to change width when columns collapse with zurb foundation template

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I'm using zurb foundation [this template](http://foundation.zurb.com/templates/feed.html).

This is a 3 columns template, and the columns collapse when window width become around under 1000 pixel.

But I don't want to make them collapse until 700 pixel. How can I change it?

In rails environment, I changed like this, but nothing seems to happen.

// foundation_and_overrides.scss

```
- // $row-width: rem-calc(1000);
+ $row-width: rem-calc(700);
```

If possible I want to delete `[ad]` column when the width is under 1000 px and collapse when under 700 px. If the implementation is not difficult, I'd prefer this behavior.

Comment: Could you tell us which version of Foundation you are using please.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're experiencing two issues here.

First, the template you reference uses the `medium` grid class. When the screen size hits the `medium` breakpoint they made the columns go full width. Here's how the rows are setup in that template:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-3 columns">
    <!-- Content Here -->
  </div>
  <div class="large-6 columns">
    <!-- Content Here -->
  </div>
  <div class="large-3 columns">
    <!-- Content Here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

To change this so the columns stay fixed until around 700px you could change the column classes to:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="medium-3 columns">
    <!-- Content Here -->
  </div>
  <div class="medium-6 columns">
    <!-- Content Here -->
  </div>
  <div class="medium-3 columns">
    <!-- Content Here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

The second issue is the `media-query` breakpoints. By default, the `$small-range` size is 0-40em. Depending on what you've set your `$rem-base` to you may need to change the ranges appropriately.

For example, if your `$rem-base` is the default `16px` this means your grid collapses to a single column (using the HTML above) at 16px * 40 = `640px`.

If you want it to collapse at exactly 700px, and your `$base-rem` is `16px` you would need to change `$small-range` to `(0em, 43.5em)`.